# Hide 'save report' option depending on page item value

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to disable the Save Report option in the interactive report action menu based on a a page item. So if the page  item is 'Y' then disable the save report option.

I did this for interactive grid and it worked. I don't know how to do this for IR.

```
function(config) {
  config.initActions = function( actions ) {
    $(() => {
      if ( $v("P0_READONLY_USER") === "Y" ) {
        apex.region("todo").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").hide("save-report");
        apex.region("todo").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").hide("show-save-report-as-dialog");
        apex.region("todo").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").hide("show-edit-report-dialog");
      }
    });
  }
  return config;
}
```

Comment: Interactive Report uses another architecture than Interactive Grid - it doesn't have any javascript APIs. Code for IG cannot be used in an IR. You could manually look for the classes of the items you want to remove and remove them using jquery. Note that any smart user can make them appear again - it's not very secure.

Comment: Typically an interactive grid can do the same as an interactive report but more. Why not just use an interactive grid that is not editable ?